# 開発環境のライブラリについて

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atom-editor, siv3d

現在私はAtomでC++を学んでいて
最近ゲームを開発しようとSiv3D等のライブラリを追加したのですが、
VisualStudio以外でライブラリを使用する方法はないのでしょうか？
検索してみたのですがVisualStudioにライブラリを入れる方法ばかりで
なかなか答えにたどり着けないため質問させて頂きました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Siv3D 動作環境](https://github.com/Siv3D/Reference-JP/wiki/%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83)には

> Siv3D でアプリケーションを開発するには、C++ による Windows デスクトップアプリケーション開発をサポートする **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** が必要です。
>   ...
>   Visual Studio 2013 以前のバージョンはサポートしていません。

とあるように単純にVisual Studioが必要なだけでなくバージョンも限定されているように見受けられます。
なお、[Visual C++はコマンドラインでのビルド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/f35ctcxw.aspx)をサポートしているため、Visual Studioをインストールした上で、Atom Editorからも適切な引数で呼び出せば使用可能です。

どのような引数が必要になるかはライブラリ側の問題よりもVisual C++の使い方に関する知識が必要とされます。その辺りがわからない・検索方法がわからない等であれば、不要なトラブルを避ける意味でもVisual Studioを使うことをお勧めします。（エラーが発生した際、自身のコーディングミスか、ライブラリのバグか、ビルド引数の誤りかを切り分けできるスキルが必要になるためです。）

Comment: なお、Siv3D に限定すれば、[OpenSiv3D](https://github.com/Siv3D/OpenSiv3D) という、対応プラットフォームを広げたものも開発が進んでいます。ご参考までに。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、どちらのライブラリにも特に興味はありませんが、見た感じOpenSiv3DであってもWindowsではVisual Studioが必要なようで、gccやclangといったキーワードは（少なくともreadmeには）表れていませんね。質問者さんの想定するプラットホームが気になりますが、Windowsを前提としているSiv3Dに目を向けられたということはやはりWindowsなのかな。